# Validate object field by conditions using Spring 3

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc

### I have a complex object that contains two BigDecimal field

```
    public class Test
    {

    private BigDecimal property1;
    private BigDecimal property2;
    //setter and getter method

    }
```

Now when user entered `property1` in spring form It should be 10% of `property2`.
This validation i have to do using spring validation framework.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestValidator implements Validator {

    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
        return Test.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    public void validate(Object obj, Errors e) {
        Test t = (Test) obj;
        if(t.getProperty1()!=0.1*t.getProperty2()){
            e.rejectValue("Test", "property1 not 10% of property2");
        }

    }
}
```